# ConvLSTM2D after a Conv2D layer in keras or tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

The process goes like this:
`x(batch, time, w, h, c)` => `Reshape` => `(batch*time, w, h, c)` => Conv2D => Reshape => `(batch,time, w, h, c')` => ConvLstm2d => ... 
The `tf.keras.layers.Reshape` can only reshape the non-batch_size portion, which I can not extract `time` from previous reshaped size `(batch*time,w,h,c)`.
Is there a decent way to achieve some model like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, `tf.keras` does not support batch dimension reshaping - if you need a layer that would do that, and still work with `tf.keras` just write a custom layer

```py
class BatchAwareReshape(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, shape, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self._shape = shape

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.reshape(inputs, self._shape)
```

Since [`tf.reshape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape) is aware of the batch dimension, you can now call the layer `BatchAwareReshape(shape=(batch*time, w, h, c))` inside your model and it will work.